# Dynamically setting material elevation

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am wanting to dynamically set the elevation of my `<mat-card>` component depending on a Boolean value.

I have read the **[following](https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation)** in the official documentation, stating that a card can change elevation with the following:

```
<mat-card 
    [class.mat-elevation-z2]="!isActive" 
    [class.mat-elevation-z8]="isActive">
  Some content
</mat-card>
```

My question is... Is there a simpler way to do this? Writing the long variable `class.mat-elevation-zX` for each elevation you may want seems a little verbose.

Would it be possible at all to do something like...

```
<mat-card [matElevation]=isActive ? 2 : 6>
    my content
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Something like `[ngClass]="'mat-elevation-z' + isActive ? 2 : 6"` should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
[ngClass]="'mat-elevation-z'+(active?2:8)"
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwqkyr?embed=1&file=app/card-overview-example.ts

Comment: Ah amazing! You can tell it's been a long day since I didn't think of this XD